# Ruby Gem simple_hashtag not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, hashtag

I am trying to get text preceding '#' become a hashtag in my Rails 4.0.0 app. I am trying to use the ruby gem [simple_hashtag](https://github.com/ralovely/simple_hashtag) 
for that purpose. The error I'm getting in my `post_controller.rb` is: `undefined method 'hashtags' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Post...>`

Here is the action in which this error occurs:

```
def index
      @posts=Post.sorted
      @posts.hashtags.each do |hashtag|
        link_to hashtag.name, path_to_hashtag(hashtag.name)
      end
  end
```

Here is the model for Post i.e. `post.rb`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include SimpleHashtag::Hashtaggable
    hashtaggable_attribute :text
end
```

Anybody can help me run this gem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is `hashtags` method is not available for `ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Post...>`

As hashtags is an object of SimpleHashtag::Hashtag class. Further this gem would create simple_hashtag_hashtags table.

`simple_hashtag_hashtags` should not be blank. If this return as a blank means have no record and would throw error as `undefined` .In case if table have no record it seems you would have made any mistake.

```
 def index
   @hashtags = SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.all
   @hashtags.each do |hashtag|
    link_to hashtag.name, path_to_hashtag(hashtag.name)
   end
  end
```

Comment: Could you tell us what _SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.all_ is returning.

Comment: Here is the result:  
`SimpleHashtag::Hashtag Load (0.0ms)  SELECT 'simple_hashtag_hashtags'.* FROM 'simple_hashtag_hashtags'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: @Muhammad Could you tell us whether our answer has been worked for you or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The gem is not maintained actively. The last commit is already [2 years old](https://github.com/ralovely/simple_hashtag/commits/master). It may not be working with recent versions of Rails.

Comment: This is incorrect. It actually does work with the latest rails straight out of the box